# How does PostgreSQL compare strings?

Tags: postgresql, collation, postgresql-9.6

I'm running Postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. The collation order is en_ZA.UTF-8. I'm puzzled by how Postgres compares strings:

```
test=> select 'b' > 'B';
 ?column? 
----------
  f

test=> select 'ba' > 'B';
?column? 
----------
  t

test=> select 'b' = 'B';
?column? 
----------
  f

test=> select 'ba' > 'C';
 ?column?  
----------
 f
```

The response to the second query doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

That's just how your locale defines sort order. Obviously  upper case letters act as tiebreakers if the string is otherwise identical - then they sort *after* lower case equivalents. But 'ba' still sorts after 'B' (and 'BA' sorts after 'b').

Compare to results without collation rules:

```
SELECT   'b' > 'B'
      , 'ba' > 'B'
      , 'ba' > 'C'
      , 'b'  > 'B' COLLATE "C"
      , 'ba' > 'B' COLLATE "C"
      , 'ba' > 'C' COLLATE "C";
```

> ```
>  ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column?
> ----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
>  f        | t        | f        | t        | t        | t
> ```

(My current collation setting `German_Germany.1252` happens to behave just like your `en_ZA.UTF-8`.)

Comment: Erwin, thanks a lot for your comment! Are you aware of a reference that rigorously defines this sorting order -- I'm still not 100% sure how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @dmitry: You might investigate the locale definitions of your OS, which provides the rules Postgres uses.

Comment: @dmitry it means it's supposed to work: First order lexicographically (case insensitive) and then, only in case of a tie, order using the cases of the characters.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ That makes perfect sense:-)